# npm mysql cannot acquire new connection once connection limit reaches

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection

I am using mysql package of npm in my NodeJS project. I am using connection pool as below -

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 50,
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: database
});
```

And then I am using the pool as -

```
pool.query("Select ....", function (err, data) {

});
```

But sometimes our database server is stuck due to large queries and I think the connection limit of this connection gets crossed. Then after the stuck queries have executed successfully, the mysql library cannot acquire new connections. I cannot even see the queries in `SHOW PROCESSLIST` of MySQL. So there is issue in acquiring new connections. There is nothing in the logs too. I sort the issue by restarting the Node Server, but it isnt the ideal solution. Please help me in identifying the cause of the issue. Similar issue occurs with MSSQL connections in NodeJS and I just cannot identify the reason for this.

Comment: Are you closing your connections after you complete the queries and return the data?

Comment: It is mentioned in the manual that connection pool automatically closes connections, so we dont need to close the connections.

Comment: And yet it isn't closing the connections.

Answer (score 0):

After you're done processing your query, you should send `pool.end()` to close the current connection.

Comment: Do we really need to do pool.end()? As the pool automatically closes connections once the query has executed, according to the manual.

Comment: You probably need to manually time them out and close them based on your statement that they are taking too long to come back and jamming up the queue.